# PHP: Override trait static method

Tags: php, oop, traits, overriding

I have a trait that has a static method that i want to override and call it again...
I tried this:

```
trait MyTrait{
    static function myMethod(){ echo "Hi from my trait".PHP_EOL; }
}
class MyClass{
    use MyTrait {
        myMethod as myMethodTrait;
    }
    static function myMethod(){
        self::myMethodTrait();
        echo "Hi from my class";
    }
}
MyClass::myMethodTrait();
```

I have this error:

```
Fatal error: Could not find trait 0 in (...)
```

Where`s the error?

Tks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried this code and it works as it should.

```
MyClass::myMethodTrait(); // returns Hi from my trait
```

and

```
MyClass::myMethod(); // returns Hi from my trait Hi from my class
```

Strictly from the code provided, there isn't an error. Maybe there's some more information you could add ?

Comment: I updated my php version and it works fine... That could be a bug of version... I was tried with php 5.4.10...

Comment: Well, taking into account that traits are available from 5.4.0, there might have been some bugs. Glad it worked out :)